# Getting collision contact force

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Is there a way to get contact force of a collision? I tried to do this by getting the velocity in the `OnCollisionEnter()` method. But it's giving velocity after the contact, which isn't useful to me.

Comment: Hi, did you ever get your problem resolved? If not, please update your question to indicate how existing answers have not successfully answered your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Absolutely! If you check the Unity docs, there is a handy variable called [`Collision.impulse`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-impulse.html). This was only introduced recently in **Unity 5.2** so if you haven't updated yet, consider doing so. (Otherwise, you'll be forced to use one of the now-deprecated solutions floating on the internet instead.)

Based on the documentation, to get the force applied you would just divide this value by the last frame's `Time.fixedDeltaTime` (since in physics, `impulse = force * time`):

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) {
    Vector3 collisionForce = col.impulse / Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    // And now you can use it for your calculations!
}
```